# Intermittent problems displaying google maps in angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, google-maps

I've got a google map embedded in an angular view and it displays (as shown below - right) some of the times and then shows up as grey (below - left) when I refresh the page.

[image]

My reference to google is in the page head like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<api_key>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My html (in the angular view), looks like this:

```
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
```

My code in the controller for the view looks like this:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressLine }, function (results, status) {

     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var myLatLng = { lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), 
                           lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng() };

     var myOptions = { zoom: 8, center: myLatLng };
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: name
          });
     }
});
```

Does anyone know why this might happen? Or have experienced this before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directive for your Google maps. The state's controller executes before the view is loaded. A directive's controller will load after the view.

There are more than likely plenty of Google Map directives out there. So just find something that already exists and tweak it.

For example: http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/